# Android Is there anyway to bring up custom phone # keypad inside an application?

Tags: android

I want to bring up a keypad for entering phone numbers.  Is there a way to display this dialog in my own activity and capture what the user enters. I need to be able to control what happens when the user clicks to call.  So I am intersting in customizing the Activity/Dialog that allows user to enter call numbers.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use an EditText for what the user enters, you can set the [inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) to `phone`. This will bring up a phone number oriented keyboard to pop up. You can then get what ever they entered in the EditText by calling `getText()` on it.